# Returning a Dataframe, a String, and an Integer from the Same R Function

Tags: r, function, return

I am making a Roulette game in R. I want my final function to return a dataframe with the statistics of each turn, a string saying "Win" or "Lose", and an integer with the player's ending balance.

I am trying to write my return like this

```
return(df, gameStatus, endingBalance)
```

I realize that this isn't correct (I guess too much Python is coming through here), but what could I do to return all three objects from the same function?

Thanks!

Comment: `return(list(df, gameStatus, endingBalance))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up answering my question. Thanks @det !

```
return(list(df, gameStatus, runningBalance))
```